# how to invoke a windows process using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, windows-services

I have a process running on my machine at port `8123`, how can I invoke or call a windows process using nodejs..?

I tried using  `request`

```
let bytes = new Buffer(xml, 'ascii')
var options = {
    url: "https://" + host + ":" + port,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(bytes),
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    requestCert: true,
    agent: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (error) cb(error)
    else cb(response)
}
request(options, callback);
```

but its returning with error code `ECONNRESET` and message as`socket hang up`

also tried `HTTP` like this

```
var options = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: port,
    method: 'POST',
    agent: false,
    headers: {
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(bytes),
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    },
};
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        cb('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
});
req.on('error', function (e) {
    cb('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
req.end();
```

this also returns the same error

Comment: That process occupies port `8123`, but does it provide HTTP service?

Comment: @shaochuancs it provides https

Comment: Does the process on port 8123 responds to a `curl` request?

Comment: @Michele no  its not

Comment: @Edison ok, so the problem resides in that process and not in your express server.

Comment: @Michele its working fine  when I used to call with the c# code base

Comment: @Edison ok then you are not replicating the same exact http call. Double check the headers / body you send from the C# code. Do you have access to that process code? Can you debug it?